# How to get permalinks on a non-Wordpress site

Tags: php, apache, xampp, hyperlink, permalinks

Hello guys I have some websites I'm currently building but I have a problem...I have pages such as `blogPosts.php?postID=7`

I would love something like `blogPosts.com/post title`

Meaning I dont want people to see the variables I'm passing..

Same applies to a couple of other pages. I was told that permalinks is the key but everywhere I check, all I see is Wordpress but I am designing my site from scratch.

I'm running XAMPP from my pc.

I would really appreciate any help..

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post what you've tried and where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: google "apache mod_rewrite tutorial"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make "clean" URLs.

You can do it using Apache configuration files and PHP.

[Here's an article which will tell you how.](http://evolt.org/node/22880/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look int into apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for starters.